# ActiveMQ: Advisory in cluster (network of brokers)

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have two ActiveMQ brokers (A and B) that are configured as a cluster of network of brokers with a static list.

Normal message consumption and store and forward works as expected. That is: messages on A with no consumers connected will be picked up by a consumer connected to broker B.

I do see that this is not the case for advisory messages.
In my current setup I have an application that is monitoring the DLQ by connecting to the advisory: `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDLQd.Queue`. I need this to trigger certain actions when messages arrive in the DLQ.

When testing the cluster I don't see any advisory messages for DLQ messages on broker A coming through to my monitoring application connected to broker B.

Any idea how I can have advisory messages also stored and forwarded just like normal queue messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advisory Messages are not really meant for that sort of thing, they are Topic based event information specific to a given broker.  The brokers can use them to discover activity on another broker or a client can listen to the broker it is connected to for information on activity there but broadcasting advisories across networks would lead to confusion as you have no context on where the advisory came from or how it was acted on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware that Advisory messages were specific for a broker and that they wouldn't be forwarded. As a step forward I'm now thinking of creating separate DLQs and my monitoring application would just consume these messages for error handling. Is this a valid solution? Is it normal that messages in a DLQ be consumed?

Comment: It is viable to consume or browse the DLQ as that is the reason messages are preserved there.