# Are the connection advisory messages forwarded across a network of brokers?

Tags: activemq-classic

I need to handle advisories messages from the ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection topic from one broker to another broker that is using a network connectors.

On broker A, that is linked broker B, if a client Ca is connecting, I would like the client Cb to receive the advisoiry message of A.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I did not tried by myself, I firstly though the Advisory topics are treated as other topics but it seems not to be the case as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59326845/628006)

The documentation on the Advisory topics does not mentions this and the above post is written by an ActiveMQ developer which seems to be a reliable source.

When connecting to Advisory topics, you have to be careful if you have authorization in place: you must give read/write access to all clients to the Advisory Topics like said in the [security doc](https://activemq.apache.org/security.html). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32093799/628006) relates exactly the issue you can have by not configuring properly the security.

On your side, I would recommend to create a network of broker with e.g. a Docker Compose and test it locally.

Further useful readings:

- https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html#NetworksofBrokers-Networksofbrokersandadvisories
- https://dzone.com/articles/how-monitor-activemq-networks
- https://dzone.com/articles/active-mq-network-brokers
- https://blog.christianposta.com/activemq/from-inside-the-code-activemq-network-bridges-and-demand-forward-subscriptions
- https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html
- https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/tutorials/handling-advisory-messages
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/ensuring-effective-amazon-mq-performance.html#network-of-brokers-configure-correctly

Comment: Ok, so you are confirming that a client A on broker A, if subscribed to the ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection topic on broker A should receive a Connection advisory message if a client B is connecting to broker B ?

Comment: I revised my answer as it seems not possible. I though first that Advisory topics are just spreaded across network but it seems not to be the case as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59326845/628006). Perhaps you can create a specific route in each brokers which subscribe to the topic and post it to a dedicated queue/topic (clients.A in broker A, clients.B in broker B, etc... ) or to create a unique topic but enrich each message with the broker originator.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That what I wanted to know.